# C# error not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me to explain what is this error about, I don't know what its mean.

> not all code paths return a value

Thank you I already solve it, It just it is not in the correct path..

Comment: Can you show your related code?

Comment: Error is self explanatory

Comment: It's a question for Google, not for stackoverflow

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question exactly but from [`Compiler Error CS0161`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cz4k9t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) _A method that returns a value must have a return statement in_ **all code paths.**

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a function that returns a bool.

```
public bool SomeMethod(int someParameter)
{
    if (someParameter == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There are two possible code paths here:

> 1. someParameter is 1 - the if statement is entered into, and the method returns true.
> 2. someParameter is any other value - the if statement is skipped, and the end of the function is reached, and no return statement is executed.

Of those two possible scenarios, only the first one returns a value.

This is not allowed because the method must by definition return a value, regardless of which code blocks within the method get executed or not.

That's what the error message means.

The way to fix is to make sure that if the condition isn't met, a return statement can still be executed, as follows:

```
public bool SomeMethod(int someParameter)
{
    if (someParameter == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, if the if statement isn't executed, the function returns false, and if it is, it returns true. What the value is doesn't matter, as long as a value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is caused by a function which through some logic does not have it's return variable assigned to.

For example here the return is only actually done in certain circumstances

```
public int GetInt(string someValue)
{
  if(someValue.Equals("Foo"))
  {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is actually not correct. The error here is `Use of unassigned local variable 'returnValue'`. You have to put the `return` in the `if` block to produce the error.

Comment: @fero good spot - updated